# How to resize the image in angular controller itself, after fetching it from database?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have uploaded an image into my database (lets just say it is of size 500*700);so wherever I use this image, it should be of size 300*300
(my users can upload their own images so all the images of different sizes)

Comment: Are you using any plugins for file upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to change physically image dimentions you can use 
https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip#resize

```
require('lwip').open('image.jpg', function(err, image){

  // check err...
  // define a batch of manipulations and save to disk as JPEG:
  image.batch()
    .resize(300,300,"linear", function(err,img){})
    .writeFile('output.jpg', function(err){
      // check err...
      // done.
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a css class to the div you put the image in. It will work everywhere you use the image.

Comment: thx for your quick response..this method would work for only one image size but in my case users would upload images, so all the images would be of different sizes

Comment: Yes, but all the images would be displayed in 300*300 or the size you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link and explore (This can be achieved with OpenCV lib ):

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html#gsc.tab=0